# Why is my wordpress website taking too much time to get response from server?

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress website is really too slow. The problem is with the TTFB...After the request is sent I have to wait up to 10 seconds or maybe more to get my first byte...How Can I figure out what is the problem? and I cant install the p3 plugin on my wordpress version.

website is too slow on every request (up to 10 seconds) and its much slower on the first request (up to 20 seconds)

My internet connection is fine, and the server is fine!

here is the insight: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aiacademy.info

Comment: You could have a lot of reason for that:
- The databse is slow
- You have too much plugins, and they consume a lot of CPU to compute
- etc

Where is your wordpress hosted?

Comment: You'll need to provide some more insight on your website. Slow TTFB's are usually caused by poorly configured plugins, poorly optimized queries (like `meta_queries`), too many plugins, or too much junk/orphaned data in the database - usually in the `options` or `postmeta` tables.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry How can I know which reason is causing my problem? I am hosting it in hostgator...Thank you!

Comment: @Xhynk How could I know which one of them ? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin like w3 total cache ?

If not, I will recommend to start with that and see if the speed increase after that (you need to check in private mode, because, if your are connected, you may not it the cache).